# How to override these Bootstrap 3 Colours

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

In Bootstrap 3 I can override brand-primary, but none of the other brand colours, such as brand-success.  Why would that be?

I am using Bootstrap as part of a Laravel 5.5 install, including the front-end tooling which includes Laravel Mix, webpack, etc.

At the top of my main.scss file, I have the following two lines:

```
@import "_variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

At the top of my _variables.scss file, I have the following two lines:

```
$brand-primary: #ff0000;
$brand-success: #ff0000;
```

As you can see, I have set both brand-primary and brand-success to pure red.

In my html, if I create a panel using `<div class="panel panel-primary">`, the panel will have a red border.  If I use `<div class="panel panel-success">` however, the panel stays its origin green colour.

When I look at the list of cascading CSS rules on the div element, I can see no trace of the red colour being overriden, so it must be that SASS  has not output it.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why can't I see the sass variable being overwritten by inspecting the element's CSS in the browser?

Sass is converted to CSS, and all of the sass variables no longer exist after that point. While sass variables may have cascading behavior *within* the context of sass, there is no cascade of sass variables that we can inspect in the browser because the browser only loads the processed CSS.

---

#### Why is `.panel-success` not using the color value I set on `$brand-primary`?

The colors applied to `.panel-success` class are not based on the `$brand-success` variable.

They are *indirectly* based on the values of `$state-success-text` and `$state-success-border`, which are **not** based on `$brand-success`

The `.success-panel` colors are directly based on the variables:

- `$panel-success-text`
- `$panel-success-border`
- `$panel-success-heading-bg`

From the [bootstrap-sass _variables partial](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss):

```
$panel-success-text:          $state-success-text !default;
$panel-success-border:        $state-success-border !default;
$panel-success-heading-bg:    $state-success-bg !default;
```

From the [bootstrap-sass _panels partial](http://.panel-primary%20%7B%20%20%20@include%20panel-variant($panel-primary-border,%20$panel-primary-text,%20$panel-primary-heading-bg,%20$panel-primary-border);%20%7D):

```
.panel-primary {
  @include panel-variant($panel-primary-border, $panel-primary-text, $panel-primary-heading-bg, $panel-primary-border);
}
```